# nth-of-type CSS selectors, how do they work?

Tags: html, css

Why isn't the css selectors for the divs working ?

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .red-color:nth-of-type(even) {
            color: red;
        }
        .blue-color:nth-of-type(odd) {
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="red-color">text</div>
    <div class="blue-color">should be blue</div>
    <div class="red-color">should be red</div>
    <div class="blue-color">text</div>  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

nth-of-type refers to the element, not the class.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        div:nth-of-type(even) {
            color: red;
        }
        div:nth-of-type(odd) {
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>odd is blue</div>
    <div>even is red</div>
    <div>odd is blue</div>
    <div>even is red</div>  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is there a css selector for odd/even elements of a certain class ?

Comment: I found this article that describes what you're asking for.
https://css-tricks.com/css-nth-of-class-selector/